# Why carousel images are flickering in React

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have added carousel functionality but the images are flickering whenever I click on next icon. It seems like I get the reflection of the previous image or the next one as I have only two images. I'm using tailwind with react. I'm adding a gif below so one can see the problem. I'm getting flickering every time. But my screen recorder shows it only the first time.

[Link to Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5VHQ.jpg)

**Index.css**

```
.slide-in-from-right {
  animation: slideInFromRight 0.5s ease-in;
}

.slide-out-to-left {
  animation: slideOutToLeft 0.5s ease-in;
}

@keyframes slideInFromRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOutToLeft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

**Hero SlideShow**

```
let count = 0;
export default function HeroSlideshow() {
  const [slide, setSlide] = useState({});
  const [clonedSlide, setClonedSlide] = useState({});
  const [slides, setSlides] = useState([]);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const slideRef = useRef();
  const clonedSlideRef = useRef();

  const { updateNotification } = useNotification();

  const fetchLatestUploads = async () => {
    const { error, movies } = await getLatestUploads();
    if (error) return updateNotification("error", error);

    setSlides([...movies]);
    setSlide(movies[0]);
  };

  //0,1,2,3,4
  const handleOnNextClick = () => {
    setClonedSlide(slides[count]);
    clonedSlideRef.current.classList.add("slide-out-to-left");
    count = (count + 1) % slides.length;
    setSlide(slides[count]);
    setCurrentIndex(count);

    slideRef.current.classList.add("slide-in-from-right");
  };

  const handleAnimationEnd = () => {
    slideRef.current.classList.remove("slide-in-from-right");
    clonedSlideRef.current.classList.remove("slide-out-to-left");
    setClonedSlide({});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLatestUploads();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="w-full flex">
      {/* Slide show section */}
      <div className="w-4/5 aspect-video relative overflow-hidden">
        <img
          ref={slideRef}
          onAnimationEnd={handleAnimationEnd}
          className="aspect-video object-cover"
          src={slide.poster}
          alt=""
        />
        <img
          ref={clonedSlideRef}
          onAnimationEnd={handleAnimationEnd}
          className="aspect-video object-cover absolute inset-0"
          src={clonedSlide.poster}
          alt=""
        />

        <SlideShowController onNextClick={handleOnNextClick} />
      </div>

      {/* Up Next Section */}
      <div className="w-1/5 aspect-video bg-red-300"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

const SlideShowController = ({ onNextClick, onPrevClick }) => {
  const btnClass =
    "bg-primary rounded border-2 text-white text-xl p-2 outline-none";
  return (
    <div className="absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 w-full flex items-center justify-between px-2">
      <button onClick={onPrevClick} className={btnClass} type="button">
        <AiOutlineDoubleLeft />
      </button>
      <button onClick={onNextClick} className={btnClass} type="button">
        <AiOutlineDoubleRight />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer if I cannot reproduce the issue but I have a clue of what's going on. When you call the method to `handleOnNextClick` you must take on mind that the slide's index (which is actually showing it as selected)'ll change almost instantly but the animation `slideInFromRight` and `slideOutToLeft` is taking **.5 seconds** to complete, so you can try to trigger the slide's index change with a *setTimeout*.

```
const handleOnNextClick = () => {
    clonedSlideRef.current.classList.add("slide-out-to-left");
    slideRef.current.classList.add("slide-in-from-right");
    count = (count + 1) % slides.length;
    setTimeout(() => {
        setClonedSlide(slides[count]);
        setSlide(slides[count]);
        setCurrentIndex(count);
    }, 500)
};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try giving us a working snippet so we can provide a working solution: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do